# Why does MediaPlayer cause errors when used outside onCreate

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a small 2 second sound effect attached to a button. When clicked, the sound effect plays and the user is taking to the next activity. The function I created is outside onCreate and uses Intent to send the user to the next activity. When I add the mp variables I get an error saying there's a problem with playGame(). What is causing the MediaPlayer to not play when it's placed in this function? Eclipse suggests changing mp.create() to MediaPlayer.create but that doesn't fix the issue.

```
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public MediaPlayer mp;
public void playGame(View view) {
    mp.create(this, R.raw.bulletricochet);
    mp.start();
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void playRules(View view) {
    Intent intentR = new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentR);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mp` object is null and yet you are calling create method on it.

To create a MediaPlayer object use `MediaPlayer.create`. You say you tried it but probably didn't assign the return value to your `mp` variable.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bulletricochet);
```